# How did Rhodey take the suit off in the military base?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-2

When Colonel James Rhodes (A.K.A. "Rhodey") stole the Mk.2 Iron Man suit and brought it to the military base, and he was shown without the suit on when Major General Meade came to inspect the suit. In Iron Man 1, it was shown that the suit needed a lot of bulky machines to get it off, and that it was quite hard to take it off even with those machines.

In Iron Man 2 (and the Avengers), it looked the machines were improved so that the suit was easy to take off, but you still needed those machines to take it off. In Iron Man 3, Tony Stark improved his suits to be able to open up so that the wearer could easily get in, but the suit that Rhodey stole was only a Mk.2 model and did not have that feature when they were in the military base.

So how exactly did Rhodey get the suit off when inside the military base before they upgraded the suit?

Comment: I think you are reading too much into the movie... The military found a way to get him out of it, it's probably just too boring or too extensive to explain in the movies.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of possible answers to this question that I can think of.

1. The military simply disassembled the suit and rebuilt it.
2. Tony built the suit intentionally for Rhodey to use, and may have already made it a lot more user friendly.

Comment: I don't think first one has much merit because they didn't have Tony's technology. second one is most probable in this list, IMO ...

Comment: What do you mean by user-friendly? Tony Stark obviously didn't develop the technology required to make the suit open or he would have used it on his main suit (and even if he had the technology, he couldn't have known which suit Rhodey would have taken).